# Removing extraneous index for groupby-apply functions that generate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

This is a problem I've encountered in various contexts, and I'm curious if I'm doing something wrong, or if my whole approach is off. The particular data/functions are not important here, but I'll include a concrete example in any case.

It's not uncommon to want a groupby/apply that does various operations on each group, and returns a new dataframe. An example might be something like this:

```
def patch_stats(df):
    first = df.iloc[0]
    diversity = (len(df['artist_id'].unique())/float(len(df))) * df['dist'].mean()
    start = first['ts']
    return pd.DataFrame({'diversity':[diversity],'start':[start]})
```

So, this is a grouping function that generates a new DataFrame with two columns, each derived from a different operation on the input data. Again, the specifics aren't too important here, but this is the issue:

When I look at the output, I get something like this:

```
result =  df.groupby('patch_idx').apply(patch_stats)
print result

             diversity               start
patch_idx                                 
0         0   0.876161 2007-02-24 22:54:28
1         0   0.588997 2007-02-25 01:55:39
2         0   0.655306 2007-02-25 04:27:05
3         0   0.986047 2007-02-25 05:37:58
4         0   0.997020 2007-02-25 06:27:08
5         0   0.639499 2007-02-25 17:40:56
6         0   0.687874 2007-02-26 05:24:11
7         0   0.003714 2007-02-26 07:07:20
8         0   0.065533 2007-02-26 09:01:11
9         0   0.000000 2007-02-26 19:23:52
10        0   0.068846 2007-02-26 20:43:03
...
```

It's all good, except I have an extraneous, unnamed index level that I don't want:

```
print result.index.names

FrozenList([u'patch_idx', None])
```

Now, this isn't a huge deal; I can always get rid of the extraneous index level with something like:

```
result = result.reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
```

But seeing how this comes up anytime I have grouping function that returns a DataFrame, I'm wondering if there's a better approach to how I'm approaching this. Is it bad form to have a grouping function that returns a DataFrame? If so, what's the right method to get the same kind of result? (again, this is a general question fitting problems of this type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your grouping function, return a `Series` instead of a `DataFrame`.  Specifically, replace the last line of `patch_stats` with:

```
return pd.Series({'diversity':diversity, 'start':start})
```

Comment: Wow. Painfully simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this same issue.

#### Solution

```
result =  df.groupby('patch_idx', group_keys=False).apply(patch_stats)
print result
```

Comment: If the grouping function returns a `DataFrame`, as it does in the question, this method gets rid of the group index and only keeps the extraneous level.

Comment: @root that is useful